# Как сохранить файл, отправленный через formData?

Tags: node.js, backend

Есть обработка пост-запроса. В запросе передается файл через formData. Вопрос: как этот файл сохранить? Чтоб он прям в виде exe лежал в моей директории?
Я поискал и нашел пакет "express-formidable", который позволяет спарсить файлы из formData. Но как мне его сохранить в файловую систему, я не понимаю...
Вот весь код сервера:

```
const express = require('express');
const formidable = require('express-formidable');\

const PORT = 8000;

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(formidable());

app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`Server works on port ${PORT}`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.send('server works, PORT is ' + PORT);
});

app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
    

});
```

Comment: а в документации чо пишут?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться либой [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), в частности методом [writeFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlewritefiledata-options), или его синхронным собратом:

```
// Создание файла
filehandle = fs.open(<имя файла>);

// Запись данных в файл
await filehandle.writeFile(<тело файла>, <опции>);
```